# Thanks for reaching out!

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've noticed this is a typical reply on social media platforms. I always thought this is a standard polite response until I encountered [this](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=thanks%20for%20reaching%20out) entry on Urban Dictionary:

> **thanks for reaching out**
>   The most obnoxious possible reply to someone who has contacted you, often used in professional settings.
>   *Hi John, thanks for reaching out. I'm quite busy right now on many important projects. Why don't you reach out to me again at this time next year and see if I have a couple of free minutes then. Or, better yet, how about never? Does never work for you?*

Is it true? What does it really mean? Is the Urban Dictionary definition a joke?

Comment: It is an often used "stock" phrase, that's all. "obnoxious" is a subjective opinion. Best not to rely too much upon Urban Dictionary for objective information.

Comment: Urban Dictionary is not a very reliable source for unbiased information.

Comment: This is definitely a joke when it comes to "next year" and "never".

Comment: I think it is most often used in a corporate setting, and would risk sounding insincere or overly-formal if used in a more personal one. I would not expect anybody to have a bad reaction to it if used in business.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reference is a somewhat cynical explanation.  "Reaching out" is commonly used in english to indicate opening a communication channel.

At work I will say "I'll 'reach out' to the graphics team to consult on the best layout".  This means that I will contact them for advice or in an ongoing capacity or in an informative capacity.

I would expect this grew from [outreach](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/outreach?s=t) - the act of extending services, benefits, etc., to a wider section of the population, as in community work.